# Sparql Wiki Data Query

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm trying to get the query results for every first_level_administrative_country_subdivision that belong to each country on a global scale using the wiki data query tool, but my query is only returning back the actual country names. I need the first level administrative sub divisions for each country.

The following is my query any help will be appreciated.

```
SELECT ?first_level_administrative_country_subdivision    ?first_level_administrative_country_subdivisionLabel     
WHERE {
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language  "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }

?first_level_administrative_country_subdivision wdt:P279 wd:Q10864048.

}
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: [this?](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Ffirst_level_administrative_country_subdivision%20%3Ffirst_level_administrative_country_subdivisionLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Ffirst_level_administrative_country_subdivision%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ10864048.%0A%7D%0ALIMIT%20100)

Comment: Thanks for the reply not exactly. I tried that earlier but that's not displaying the actual states that belong to each country. I'm trying to get every state that belongs to each country on a global scale.

For example for the United States it would Be California, New York, New Jersey etc...

Comment: Rather [this](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%20%3Fsubdivision%20%3FsubdivisionLabel%20%3FsubdivisiontypeLabel%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Fsubdivision%20wdt%3AP31%20%3Fsubdivisiontype%20.%0A%20%20%3Fsubdivisiontype%20wdt%3AP279%20wd%3AQ10864048%20.%0A%20%20%3Fsubdivisiontype%20wdt%3AP17%20%3Fcountry%20.%0A%23%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3024240%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3Fcountry%20)